# How to set video as wall paper

Tags: video, mfc, wallpaper

I'm developing an application using MFC. Is it possible to set video as a wall paper behind the desktop icons?

Thank you.

Anam G

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with DirectX I believe. I've never tried to do such a thing so I couldn't tell you where to start. I can tell you that [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) does it [as shown here](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aPlay_HowTo/Basic_Use/Video#DirectX_Wallpaper). VLC is open source so if you feel adventurous you could dive into their source code to see how they do it.

Comment: I have reviewed VLC source code. It uses Direct X. but to set video window behind desktop icon, it takeout the desktop's top window handle and set their window as child window. But it does not work in Win 7. It works in Win XP.

Comment: That's what I thought it might be doing. It should work with Windows 7 with the basic desktop theme. I.e. [it doesn't look like it works with the Aero desktop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18167/set-a-video-as-your-desktop-wallpaper-with-vlc/#comment-136074). Like I said, I've never tried so I can't be more specific. This does look like it might be an interesting experiment for this weekend though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, there is no official way of doing this.

More nuanced answer: In Windows versions before Vista, there was something called 'active desktop'. With this you could set pretty much anything to be your desktop background. However it's being phased out and not a real option anymore for doing what you want. The only way to get it to work is through hackery like what vlc does - get the desktop window handle and do nasty things to it. Recent versions of Windows have better protection against such tomfoolery; there are probably ways around those protections but then you'll end up in an arms race with the Windows developers. So, even in the nuanced version, the answer remains 'no there is no reliable and supported way of doing it, and as such, you shouldn't do it'. Any application that *does*, should be and often is (and rightly so) classified as rogue software of malware.